# passing arm parameters to a powershell customize section of a Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates template

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

When creating a Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates template I find it difficult to pass an ARM parameter to an customize powershell section of the template. I find it hard because every line of powershell is an array item and should be included in double quotes. I get an error when having the template configured like below in Azure DevOps.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "westeurope"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "westeurope"
    },
    "buildTimeoutInMinutes": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 120
    },
    "vmSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_DS4_v2"
    },
    "osDiskSizeGB": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 0
    },
    "sharedImageGalleryResourceId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "sharedImageGalleryImageName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "identityResourceId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "imageName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "imageSource": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetResourceId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "imageTemplateName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "buildVersionNumber": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccountResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "baseTime": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[utcNow('u')]"
    },
    "SASURL":{
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "example"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "imageName": "[if(equals(parameters('imageName'),''),concat('1.',parameters('buildVersionNumber')),parameters('imageName'))]",
    "galleryImageId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('storageAccountResourceGroup'),'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/',parameters('sharedImageGalleryResourceId'),'/images/',parameters('sharedImageGalleryImageName'),'/versions/',variables('imageName'))]",
    "storageAccount": "[resourceid(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
    "accountSasProperties": {
        "signedServices": "b",
        "signedResourceTypes": "co",
        "signedPermission": "rwdl",
        "signedExpiry": "[dateTimeAdd(parameters('baseTime'), 'PT1H')]"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('imageTemplateName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates",
        "apiVersion": "2020-02-14",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "identity": {
            "type": "UserAssigned",
            "userAssignedIdentities": {
                "[parameters('identityResourceId')]": {}
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "buildTimeoutInMinutes": "[parameters('buildTimeoutInMinutes')]",
            "vmProfile": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]",
                "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSizeGB')]",
                "vnetConfig": {
                    "subnetId": "[parameters('subnetResourceId')]"
                }
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "SharedImageVersion",
                "imageVersionId": "[parameters('imageSource')]"
            },
            "customize": [
                {
                    "type": "PowerShell",
                    "name": "Set Background Color",
                    "runElevated": true,
                    "inline": [
                        "cd HKCU:\\",
                        "set-location -path HKCU:\\Control Panel\\Desktop",
                        "[concat('Set-ItemProperty -Path \"HKCU:\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" -Name \"WallPaper\" -Value \" \" -PropertyType \"String\"')]",
                        "[concat('Set-ItemProperty -Path \"HKCU:\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" -Name \"Background\" -Value \"0 0 0\" -PropertyType \"String\"')]"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "PowerShell",
                    "name": "Download AzCopy",
                    "runElevated": true,
                    "scriptUri": "https://stdnbdareaibsourcedt.blob.core.windows.net/imagesoftware/DownloadAzCopy.ps1"
                 },
                {
                    "type": "PowerShell",
                    "name": "Download Software",
                    "runElevated": true,
                    "inline": [
                        "$SASURLvar = [parameters('SASURL')]",
                        "$container = 'imagesoftware'",
                        "$blob = 'office16.zip'",
                        "$urlPathToAdd = $container + '/' + $blob",
                        "$downloadURL = $SASURLvar.Insert($SASURLvar.IndexOf('?'),$urlPathToAdd)",
                        "$cmd = \"C:\\temp\\azcopy.exe copy $downloadURL C:\\temp\"",
                        "invoke-expression $cmd",
                        "Expand-Archive -LiteralPath \"C:\\temp\\office16.zip\"  -DestinationPath \"C:\\temp\\\""
                        ]
                }


            ],
            "distribute": [
                {
                    "type": "SharedImage",
                    "galleryImageId": "[variables('galleryImageId')]",
                    "runOutputName": "shareimage",
                    "excludeFromLatest": true,
                    "replicationRegions": [
                        "westeurope"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "galleryImageId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('galleryImageId')]"
    },
    "imageTemplateResourceId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates', parameters('imageTemplateName'))]"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the exact error you see?

Answer (score 0):

I normally save my templates  / parameter files with "tags" in a blob so for example, if this was a portion of my template, like it is in yours:

```
"vmSize": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "<vmsize>"
},
```

Then run my powershell script:

$vmsize = "Standard_B4ms"

$templateBlob = "https://blob.SAS.url"
$template =  $env:userprofile+"\newVm.json"

Invoke-WebRequest - uri $templateBlob -outfile $template -useBasicParsing

(Get-Content -Path $template -Raw) -replace "",$vmSize                | Set-Content $template

New-azResourceGroupDeployment -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName -TemplateFile $template -TemplateParametersFile $params

By doing this, I would have successfully replaced the "tag" with the value and the portion of the json template passed to the ARM would look like this:

```
"vmSize": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "Standard_B4ms"
},
```